# Symfony - get "Redirect From" route in Controller

Tags: php, security, routes, symfony-3.4

I need to know what route user request before been redirect to login if He is an anonymous user. I can see this information from developer bar, but I would get this in controller for customize a message to the User.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm getting it in Symfony 4:

```
$redirectRoute = $request->getSession()->get("_security.main.target_path");
```

Comment: @NicolaPez, hopefully this is still relevant to you after 11 months.  ~